# byte hex calculation in java

Tags: java, byte, hex

i am an amature in byte..hex calculation etc...my application requires me to send some data through sockets in the form of bytes...

```
1st byte -> [ { ]
2nd byte -> [ { ]
3rd byte  -> [ 0xD1 ]
4th byte -> [ 0x00 ]
5th byte -> [sum of first,second and third hex value]
6th byte -> [ } ]
7th byte -> [ } ]
```

This is a sample
How can i perform such an operation of assigningthe hex values in each byte, storing these bytes in an array.. I got a bit stuck up with this.. could someone help me out ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can build up array of bytes like :

```
    byte[] data = new byte[7];

    data[0] = "{".getBytes()[0];
    data[1] = "{".getBytes()[0];
    data[2] = (byte) 0xd1;
    data[3] = (byte) 0x00;
    data[4] = (byte) 0xd1 + 0x00;
    data[5] = "}".getBytes()[0];
    data[6] = "}".getBytes()[0];
```

Comment: hey...thnks a lot...this is what i wanted... :)

Comment: What about:
`byte[] data = new byte[7];
    data[0] = '{';
    data[1] = '{';
    data[2] = (byte) 0xd1;
    data[3] = (byte) 0x00;
    data[4] = (byte) 0xd1 + 0x00;
    data[5] = '}';
    data[6] = '}';`
?

Answer (score 1):

Hex is just a notation for the value in the byte. Add them together using ordinary `+`.

Comment: okie...how can i create individual bytes ? How do i assign individual values ?

Comment: `byte a = 0x11; byte b = 0x22 ; byte c = a + b;`

Answer (score 1):

People often confuse the representation of a number with the value of a number for some reason.  The values you are adding are not hexadecimal or decimal or binary.  They are just numbers.  A byte is a byte.  You can just add two bytes with + and there's nothing magical about it.  It works the same whether you show the results as hex or decimal or anything:

Example:

```
  0x2A (42)
+ 0x13 (19)
= 0x3D (61)
```

Comment: hi... i got the idea of adding up hex values...i asked the question wrong..i actually meant...how do i assign each hex value to individual byte ? how does it work?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not actually very familiar with Java, but I am familiar with C#, which is similar.  Does Java support something like declaring a byte array with "byte[] myArray = new byte[7];" and assigning values like "myArray[3] = 0xd1;"?